# Admin unable to login using external authentication module in drupal

Tags: drupal

I am trying to develop an external authentication module in Drupal which will authenticate against an external LDAP/DB. I have tried the following code in the **module_login_validate**.

```
$response = ext_auth_validate($username, $password); //returns true if auth successful
if($response){
  user_external_login_register($username, 'modulename');
}
```

i am able to login non-admin users, but when the admin enters the local credentials, i get an **Integrity constraint violation** stating that the entry for **admin** already exists. I figured that the user_external_login_register tries to add the user. Is there any way the admin can default to his local credentials?